# BLE device disconnects after sometime

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using two BLE devices for connection to establish using bgapi library. After sometime both devices disconnect abruptly at the same time. I don't know where to look into as I can't see any errors that is logged.
Connection for one device is working fine but issue is with the connecting two devices.
Most importantly it is not happening every time.(Out of five tries devices are disconnecting once)

I tried udev blacklist. I thought modem manager might be interfering but of no use.

Comment: You can use btmon (as root) to log everything that happens. That should give disconnect reason.

Comment: I ran "sudo btmon" but it is not logging anything. One more thing I want to mention that I stopped bluetooth.service using systemctl and then tried to connect the devices, it got connected(but above problem still happened) which was surprising.